# Function to calculate "Persistence Rate" by group with a logical argument to determine whether to include overall persistence

Tags: r

**The Function**

"Persistence Rate" is also sometimes referred to as "retention rate". It is the number of ID's in a given term/period that are also found in the next term/period. *(e.g., I have 10 customers in October but only 3 of those customers return in November. My persistence rate is then 30%.)*

I have written a function to calculate persistence from a dataframe containing a list of ID's and the rank of the term/period *(e.g., October is ranked 10 out of all the 12 months)*. The function uses `tidyeval`. It has all of the necessary arguments -- data, id, and rank. I also included a period argument so that the output is easily interpreted. *(e.g., output "October" instead of 10)*. I also included a grouping argument (...) *(e.g., persistence rates by gender)*. The `rmax` assignment is so I can filter out the last term, since you wouldn't be able to calculate the last terms persistence rate. All of this fits pretty neatly into one `dplyr` chain.

But I wanted to add an "overall" argument. The overall argument would be a logical argument, indicating whether or not to include the entire population's persistence rate (not considering the term or grouping variables).

Here is what I came up with:

```
  persist_sum <- function(df, id, period, rank, ..., overall = FALSE){

  rmax <- max(df[deparse(substitute(rank))])

  enq_period <- enquo(period)
  enq_id <- enquo(id)
  enq_rank <- enquo(rank)
  enq_group_var <- quos(...)

   out <- df %>%
          group_by(UQ(enq_id)) %>%   
          arrange(UQ(enq_rank)) %>% 
          mutate(nextrank = lead(UQ(enq_rank))) %>% 
          group_by(UQS(enq_group_var), UQ(enq_period), UQ(enq_rank)) %>% 
          summarize(persistence_rate=sum(nextrank == UQ(enq_rank) + 1, na.rm = TRUE)/n()) %>%
          filter(!! enq_rank != rmax) %>%
          select(- UQ(enq_rank))

   if(overall == TRUE){
    total <- df %>%
              group_by(UQ(enq_id)) %>%   
              arrange(UQ(enq_rank)) %>% 
              mutate(nextrank = lead(UQ(enq_rank))) %>% 
              ungroup()%>%
              filter(UQ(enq_rank)!= rmax)%>%
              summarize(persistence_rate=sum(nextrank == (UQ(enq_rank) + 1), na.rm = TRUE)/n())%>%
              as.numeric()

    out <- out %>%
            mutate(overall = total)
     }

  return(out)
}
```

**The Problem/Question**

Any suggestions for how to improve this code would be welcome, but my main concern is that calculating the overall persistence rate using the `if()` statement uses a lot of code. I feel like I should be able to more efficiently incorporate the logical argument into my `dplyr` chain.

Any recommendations for reducing the amount of text in this code? Also looking for best practices when it comes to incorporating arguments into the code.

**Practice Data**

Here is the practice data that I have been using to test this function. It also works on the real data that it is intended for.

```
dataFrame <- data.frame(id = as.character(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2)), 
                        period = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                        rank = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
                        group = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```