# Function to calculate Persistence Rate with optional group_by variable and logical arguments

Tags: r

**The Function**

"Persistence" is sometimes also referred to as "retention". It is defined as the number of units (ID's) in a given term/period that are also found in the subsequent term/period. So, if I have 10 customers in period 1, and 3 of those customers return in period 2, my persistence rate is 30%.

I have written a function that will either:

1. Calculate the persistence rate for each period's cohort of ID's
   if    `calculate = TRUE`.
2. Create an indicator variable on the original dataframe that
   identifies whether the ID persisted (1) or not (0), if
   `calculate = FALSE`.

Furthermore, if `overall = TRUE` when `calculate = TRUE`, it will include the persistence rate over all of the terms.

**The Arguments**

Here is a brief description about each of the arguments:

- **df** (*REQUIRED*): This is the dataframe argument, and a dataframe should be passed to this argument.
- **id** (*REQUIRED*): This is the unique identification of the observational unit of interest. (Customer ID, Product ID, Student ID, etc.)
- **rank** (*REQUIRED*): This is the numeric or ordered factor argument that defines the sequence of periods.
- **period** (*OPTIONAL*): This is the "label" or more interpretative version of rank. Essentially just makes output pretty, if desired. (e.g., "October" is the period, 10 is the ranking number for October)
- **...** (*OPTIONAL*): Variables to `group_by` in case a comparison of persistence rates across groups is desired.
- **overall** (*REQUIRED w/ DEFAULT*): Logical variable to decide whether or not to include an "overall" persistence rate calculation.
- **calculate** (*REQUIRED w/ DEFAULT*): Logical variable to decide whether to summarize the data into persistence rates, or to create an indicator variable denoting persistence.

**Perceived Improvement Areas**

Of course, any and all suggestions for ways to improve this function are greatly appreciated. I do, however, have some areas that I *think* could be improved, I'm just not sure how.

1. **Grouping the Optional `period` Argument**: In the section that describes what to do if `calculate == TRUE`, I had to create an `if` statement to group the variables differently depending on whether the `period` argument was supplied. Before, there was only one `group_by` argument, and if I explicitly called *all* of the arguments, the function would work great. But when I only called the first 3 required arguments, I would get an error. The current version works fine, but *is there a better way to conditionally group optional variables?*
2. **Conditional `overall` Argument**: In order to calculate the overall persistence, it seems like I have to repeat a lot of code, which could be computationally expensive, and is a little less easy to read than one continuous `dplyr` chain would be. *Is there a more code-efficient way to calculate the overall rate?*

**What I've Already Tried**

I tried to make things a little more efficient by creating the indicator variable 1st, whether or not `calculate == TRUE`. The I just summarised the `persistence_indicator` by group. But when I used `system.time()` to compare performance before and after, my current function was more efficient in almost every combination of arguments. In retrospect, this makes sense. Why create that variable if I don't need it when `calculate == TRUE`.

I also tried posting [an earlier version of my function here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/198152/function-to-calculate-persistence-rate-by-group-with-a-logical-argument-to-det) on Code Review, just to be completely transparent. It didn't get much attention, which is probably fine since the function has changed so much. But I am still interested in general best practices for improving code, especially as it relates to conditionals.

**Sample Data**

```
dataFrame <- data.frame(id = as.character(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2)), 
                        period = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
                        rank = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                        group = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**The Function Code**

```
persistence <- function(df, id, rank, period, ..., overall = TRUE, calculate = TRUE){

  stopifnot(!missing(df), !missing(id), !missing(rank))
  period_missing <- missing(period)
  
  enq_id <- enquo(id)
  enq_rank <- enquo(rank)
  enq_period <- enquo(period)
  enq_group_var <- quos(...)
  
  valid_rank_type <- is.numeric(rlang::eval_tidy(enq_rank, df)) | is.ordered(rlang::eval_tidy(enq_rank, df))
  
  
  if(!valid_rank_type){
    stop("Argument \"rank\" must be numeric or ordered factor")
  }
  
  if(is.logical(calculate)){
    calculate <- calculate
  } else {
    stop("Argument \"calculate\" must be logical (TRUE/FALSE)")
  }
  
  if(is.logical(overall)){
    overall <- overall
  } else{
    stop("Argument \"overall\" must be logical (TRUE/FALSE)")
  }

  df <- df %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(denseRank = dense_rank(UQ(enq_rank)))%>%
        group_by(UQ(enq_id))%>%
        arrange(denseRank)%>%
        mutate(nextrank = lead(denseRank))
  
  if(calculate == FALSE){
    
        out <- df %>%
          mutate(persistence_indicator = case_when(nextrank == denseRank + 1 ~ 1,
                                              TRUE ~ 0))%>%
          ungroup()%>%
          select(-nextrank, -denseRank)
        
          return(out)
    
  } else if (calculate == TRUE) {
        
        if(period_missing){
          out <- df %>%
                group_by(UQS(enq_group_var), UQ(enq_rank), denseRank)
        } else if(!period_missing){
          out <- df %>%
                group_by(UQS(enq_group_var), UQ(enq_rank), UQ(enq_period), denseRank)
        }
    
    
         out <- out %>%
                summarize(persistence_rate = sum(nextrank == (denseRank+1), na.rm = TRUE)/n(),
                          count = n()) %>%
                ungroup()%>%
                filter(denseRank != max(denseRank))%>%
                arrange(denseRank) %>%
                select(-denseRank)
         
         if(overall == TRUE){
          total <- df %>%
                    ungroup()%>%
                    filter(denseRank != max(denseRank))%>%
                    summarize(persistence_rate=sum(nextrank == (denseRank + 1), na.rm = TRUE)/n())%>%
                    as.numeric()
           
          out <- out %>%
                  mutate(overall = total)
         }
    return(out)
  }
}
```

**Sample Function Call, Output, and sessionInfo()**

```
library(dplyr)

persistence(df = dataFrame,
            id = id,
            rank = rank,
            period = period,
            group,
            overall = TRUE,
            calculate = TRUE)

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  group  rank period persistence_rate count   overall
  <dbl> <dbl>  <chr>            <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
1     1     1      A              1.0     2 0.7142857
2     2     1      A              0.5     2 0.7142857
3     1     2      B              0.5     2 0.7142857
4     2     2      B              1.0     1 0.7142857

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2.2 dplyr_0.7.6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.3 compiler_3.4.2   magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2        
 [6] tools_3.4.2      glue_1.2.0       tibble_1.3.4     yaml_2.1.14      Rcpp_0.12.17    
[11] pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.2.1      purrr_0.2.4      bindr_0.1.1
```

**Final Note**

The data I use interactively to test this function has about 15,000 rows, so when I mentioned performance above using `system.time()`, it was with much more data that the sample data I have provided. The sample data works just fine.

Comment: What exactly you want to improve to this function?

Comment: I want to improve this function by using code that follows best practices. So,  what are the best practices for incorporating optional arguments into a `dplyr` `group_by()` chain? And what are the best practices for incorporating a conditional statement, as directed by an argument? Does my code follow those practices, does it get close? Is there a reason I shouldn't use the method I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments in no specific order (mostly from top of your code to bottom):

- What you refer to as conditional `group_by` can be done with `group_by_at`. Define your values before with an `if` call, then have a single pipe chain using `group_by_at`. See also `group_if`
- Your code isn't commented at all (though arguments documented)
- `tidyverse` functions usually use argument names that start with a dot when they contain an `...`, so there are fewer chances of argument conflicts.
- You call `quo` and not `rlang::quo` but you call `rlang::eval_tidy`, so not 100% consistent (unless it would conflict with another `eval_tidy` function?).
- On the `valid_rank_type <- ...` line you should use `||` unless you're comparing vectors or you want it to fail if rhs returns an error and lhs is `TRUE`
- Use `if_else` rather than `case_when` if you only have 2 case : `case_when(nextrank == denseRank + 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))` becomes `if_else(nextrank == denseRank + 1, 1, 0)`
- I don't understand what sense make `calculate <- calculate` or `overall <- overall`
- Instead of using `if(calculate == FALSE)` and `if(calculate == TRUE)` you can use `if(!calculate)` and `if(calculate)` (as you did with `if(period_missing)`
- It's generally good practice (though not a hard rule) not to use return call in the middle of the code when they can be avoided. In your case you could remove them and add out as a last line before exiting the function.
- `sum(nextrank == (denseRank+1), na.rm = TRUE)/n()` is `mean(nextrank == (denseRank+1), na.rm = TRUE)`
- It's not very "tidyesque" to finish your pipe chain with `as.numeric` here, though it does the job, the function that would make sense to me here is `dplyr::pull`